# Is the Kotlin documentation correct?

Tags: kotlin

Is the code (show below) correct? It was take from page 63 of the Kotlin-docs.pdf, which is also the last code snippet of https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

```
 fun <T> cloneWhenGreater(list: List<T>, threshold: T): List<T> 
 where T : Comparable, T : Cloneable {
 return list.filter { it > threshold }.map { it.clone() }
 }
```

Taken by as is, the compiler fails with:
1. **One type argument expected for interface Comparable defined in kotlin**
2. **Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is List but List was expected**
3. **Cannot access 'clone': it is protected in 'Cloneable'**

The first two errors are easily resolved by changing the code to the following:

```
 fun <T> cloneWhenGreater(list: List<T>, threshold: T): List<Any>
        where T : Comparable<in T>, T : Cloneable {
    return list.filter { it > threshold }.map { it.clone() }
}
```

I still get the following error:
***Cannot access 'clone': it is protected in 'Cloneable'***

I'm using Kotlin 1.1.2-release-IJ2017.1-1

Am I missing something? or is there an error in the documentation?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems the documentation is indeed wrong. You should file a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: That particular snipped was [added in June 2014](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-web-site/commit/9c37f55e46d0fbf6e48fd3e6c8ceef4957ba91cd#diff-738f9741f732f1c2b4254272e8e84d1fR257), and only once altered in [October 2015](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-web-site/commit/e16ad494290f8093a91a6c4b5d2cc8822b86b06f#diff-738f9741f732f1c2b4254272e8e84d1fR285), with a change that broke it even more. It might be that it did compile back then, but at that point Kotlin was still in rapid development.

Comment: Thanks! Filed a bug (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18144). Will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`it.clone()` returns `Any` and you get error casting List to List.
So, you have changed it to List.

Your next error is **Cannot access clone: it is protected in Cloneable**.

This problem can be solved by creating our own Cloneable interface with public method.